# Visual Studio Express 2017 disassembly window missing

Tags: visual-studio

I can't find the disassembly window in Visual Studio Express 2017. In previous versions, in debug mode it was in the menu : Debug -> Windows. I checked if there is an "expert mode" in the options and I haven't found any. Does someone knows where it is?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a way. I had to reset the environment settings and set it to the Visual C++ scheme. The menu is now there, along with the Memory and Registers menu items. I think that I used the Visual Basic Scheme at first. That's probably why the menus were not there.

Answer (score 2):

### To display the Disassembly window

- On the **Debug** menu, choose **Windows**, and click **Disassembly**. The
  debugger must be running or in break mode.

Here is the reference: [How to: Use the Disassembly Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3cwf295.aspx)

Comment: It worked in 2015, but in 2017 the Disassembly menu item isn't there.